# constant error with bean name

Tags: java, xml, spring, property-placeholder

recently I decided to play with Spring. I did some tutorials and everything seems fine until the moment I am trying to use multiple properties files. As Internet says, it is enough to do something like

```
<bean  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="location">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:readData.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:sendMail.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Well, unfortunately It does not work. Surprisingly this version works (for one properties folder):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:readData.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

The Console says as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource' for property 'location'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [org.springframework.core.io.Resource] for property 'location': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [java.util.ArrayList]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:657)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at corrected_reminder.Reminder.main(Reminder.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource' for property 'location'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [org.springframework.core.io.Resource] for property 'location': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [java.util.ArrayList]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:468)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [org.springframework.core.io.Resource] for property 'location': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [java.util.ArrayList]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:260)
    at  org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 16 more
```

Could anyone help me?

**Edit**

@Denis Makarskiy 
I have tried it many times, but without satisfying results. Now I have

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [property-placeholder]
Offending resource: class path resource [Beans.xml]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using multiple properties file, use "locations" instead of "location". For single properties, you can use "location".

check the api doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setLocations-org.springframework.core.io.Resource...-

Answer (score 0):

You can use context:property-placeholder tag to specify multiple property files.

Example:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="readData.properties,
                                            sendMail.properties"/>
```

Don't forget to add **context** schema to the beans tag, like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd>
```